# How to know if a Dropwizard service started as soon as it started?

Tags: java, dropwizard

Can I base on "started" text in its `STDOUT`? Is there a standard way for this?

I'm basically trying to find a way to know it without pinging the WebApp and without having a timeout. I'm trying to find a reliable way.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but shouldn't this be the case after the `run()` method (on your `Service` class) returns?

Comment: @MichaelBerry My question is about external program be able to detect this, not from inside the Dropwizard app. Thanks

Comment: Can you modify the webapp? Or is that set in stone, and you can only modify the external program?

Comment: @MichaelBerry I can modify the external program. Webapp is not owned by me. Also, I would like to use this technique for newer services as well. (Basically I would like to know integration tests(integration tests of the external program using this service), whether the service is started.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't modify the webapp, and it doesn't give you any other notification, then there's going to be no better way than pinging it and seeing if it's up every second or so. It might feel a bit inelegant, but in reality there's nothing wrong with that approach. I'm assuming here that it's going to start up within a few seconds - if it's going to be in the order of minutes / hours before it's up, then it might be worth combining this with reading the "started" text of stdout (though this approach seems a bit more fragile.)

If you could modify it (or build a wrapper around it), and don't like the "keep pinging it" approach, then the only other way would be to use some kind of inter process communication (such as over a localhost socket) so that you could connect to it, and it could push out a message to you when it had spun up. Worth pointing out though that in most scenarios, the additional effort of this approach won't be warranted.